# How to add a NSColorPicker to the application's main window?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm building an application to generate an array of colors based on a color chosen by the user.

The default on Mac OS X for color selection is to open a NSColorPanel containing multiple NSColorPickers. But, as the color selection process is the main interaction the user will have with the app, it'd be better to avoid the extra clicks and panel-popping in favor of a more straightforward way.

So, is there any way to add a NSColorPicker object to a window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interresting Question.

I strongly doubt it (but would love to be proven wrong).  NSColorPickers are not NSControls (nor NSCells) so there's no clean wrapper to insert into a window.

Even if you were to instanciate an NSColorPanel and get a reference to its contentView and copy it (with all that defines the color picking controls) to your own window... there's no obvious way of obtaining the color value.  NSColorPickers are plug-ins so you can't forsee the controls of a colorPicker.

The only other way I can see (and that's a stretch) would be to manually load the [NSColorPickers plug-ins](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/AddingColorPickers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000793-BAJBFGED) directly.  I don't know how successfull this would be.

File a bug report and request the feature?

Comment: I guess it's related to the singleton approach they took on NSColorPanel. I'll have to write my own class.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question, but check out `NSColorWell`. [From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/ChoosingColors.html):

```
NSColorWell is an NSControl for selecting and displaying a single color value.
```

Comment: The solution is to use NSColorWell as yourfriendzak has said; clicking on these will bring up the NSColorPicker (panel).